# Drupal 7 - do something in a taxonomy hook after the database has been updated

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

I would like to do something after a taxonomy item has been inserted or updated.  I tried using hook_taxonomy_term_update and hook_taxonomy_term_insert. However, anything you put here will execute *before* the database is updated.  How can I do something *after* the database has been updated?

Specifically, what I'm doing is updating a text file that lists all the taxonomy terms.  I pull this information from the database, so the db needs to be up to date before I write to the text file.

Answer (score 0):

what you could use is 
[drupal_register_shutdown_function()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_register_shutdown_function/7)

another option is to use module [hook_post_action](https://www.drupal.org/project/hook_post_action)